# Disable click on background UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am loading a `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` on the click of a `UITableViewCell`.

```
self.peoplePicker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
self.peoplePicker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
[self.peoplePicker setDelegate:self];
self.peoplePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:self.peoplePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the picker is presented as `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`, I want to disable the `UIViewController` behind it. For that I could load a transparent view on presenting the picker and dismiss it when the picker is dismissed. So the tap on the viewcontroller wont work.
I would like to know if there is another way to do it, where I wouldn't require to create a new `UIView` and load/dismiss it.

Comment: When you present view controller as form sheet, it by default disable the view behind it ie it shows grey view behind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `setUserInteractionEnabled` property on the view of the ViewController before presenting and after dismissing the Picker view.